# Is it possible to catch DirectX11 runtime messages for logging?

Tags: logging, directx, message

As the title says, I'm wondering if it's possible to catch the runtime messages DX11 produces when something is wrong. For example, when trying to load a file that can't be found you'll get: `D3DX11: ID3DX11DataLoader::Load - can't open "FilePath" in VS output`.

I'm wondering because I'd like to log it in my application error log.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, all error messages are just outputed to the debug console. Try something like

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString

I think that these messages are logged using OutputDebugString. Try downloading DevugView from sysinternals. If the debug messages are shown there, you can capture them yourself and log them.